# Least common integer java?

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

How can I detect the opposite of mode in java?

For instance, if I wanted to find the least common number in an array of numbers, how would I go about doing that?

Thanks.

What I've tried:

```
public int getLeastCommonNum(int[] array)
{
int min = array[0];
int pos = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] < min) 
    {
    min = array[i]; 
    pos = i; 
    }
}
return array[pos];
}
```

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618650/java-finding-the-least-common-integer-in-a-sorted-array

Comment: I've already looked through there, not much help.

Comment: Alright, but __what else have you tried?__

Comment: Making my own, didn't go so well.

Comment: Whether it went well or not, people on here will be more inclined to help you if you show your sincere and most importantly, that you don't come off as a leech. Even though you think it isn't good, post it anyway. The influx of response will increase. Plus, also tag this question as `java` - that'll help a lot.

Comment: that's great. Much better!

Comment: Define "least common", including breaking ties if applicable

Comment: It appears that you are finding the smallest element in the array.  Which would be useful, if your array told you how many occurrences there were in the original array.  But you've skipped that step.

Answer (score 1):

Here I propose a solution using `HashMap`:

```
public int getLeastCommonNum(int[] array)
{
    Map<Integer, Integer> occurrences = new HashMap<Integer, Integer> ();
    for (int num : array) {
       if (occurrences.containsKey(num)) {
           occurrences.put(num, occurrences.get(num) + 1);
       } else {
           occurrences.put(num, 1);
       }
    }
    int minOccurred = -1;
    int minOccurredCnt = -1;
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> occurrencesEntry : occurrences.entrySet()) {
        if (minOccurredCnt == -1 || minOccurredCnt > occurrencesEntry.getValue()) {
            minOccurredCnt = occurrencesEntry.getValue();
            minOccurred = occurrencesEntry.getKey();
        }
    }
    return minOccurred ;
}
```

I have coded everything by heart, so it might be that I have some small spelling mistake.

Comment: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable @  'occurrances' for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> occurancesEntry : occurances) {

Comment: Edited to change `contains()` to `containsKey()`

Comment: @RC. Thank you too, for fixing this another mistake of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Boris Strandjev version, but using [`Multiset`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multiset) for counting:

```
@Nullable
public Integer getLeastCommonNumV2(final int[] array)
{
    // step 1: count
    final Multiset<Integer> occurances = HashMultiset.create();
    for (final int num : array) {
        occurances.add(num);
    }

    // step 2: find least common
    Multiset.Entry<Integer> leastCommon = null;
    for (final Multiset.Entry<Integer> occurance : occurances.entrySet()) {
        if (leastCommon == null || occurance.getCount() < leastCommon.getCount()) {
            leastCommon = occurance;
        }
    }
    return leastCommon == null ? null : leastCommon.getElement();
}
```